# Eclipse Oxygen report errors when I click "Sync Graphviz Export" , a button of GEF DOT plug_in

Tags: java, eclipse, graphviz, eclipse-gef

Eclipse contain a Dot Editor and graphviz Dot Graph, so I want to edit graph files with it.
I download the newest Eclipe JAVA and intall all the GEF packages available in http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases.
After that, I edited a simple graphviz .dot file, and then click "Sync Graphviz Export",but it did not render any output graph,instead of the error message belowe was reported in DOT Graph windows. 
Please tell me what should I do to fix it.

**dot file:**

```html
digraph {

    2 -> 4 [arrowtail=box label="hello"];
    4 -> 5 [arrowhead=box];
    2 -> 5 ;
}
```

**DOT Graph messages**

```html
Plug-in "org.eclipse.gef.dot.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.gef.dot.internal.ui.DotGraphView".
```

**detals:**

```html
<p>


org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.gef.dot.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.gef.dot.internal.ui.DotGraphView".
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:59)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:101)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:293)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:331)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:546)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:530)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:97)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:679)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:97)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:679)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:704)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1076)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas
 at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.ui.MvcFxUiModule.bindFXCanvasFactory(MvcFxUiModule.java:57)
 at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.ui.MvcFxUiModule.configure(MvcFxUiModule.java:141)
 at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
 at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
 at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
 at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:92)
 at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:172)
 at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
 at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
 at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
 at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
 at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
 at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.gef.dot.internal.ui.DotGraphView.<init>(DotGraphView.java:127)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
 ... 113 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to locate JavaFX. Please make sure you have a JDK with JavaFX installed eg on Linux you require an Oracle JDK
 at org.eclipse.fx.osgi.fxloader.FXClassLoader.postFindClass(FXClassLoader.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.searchHooks(BundleLoader.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:463)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 135 more


</p>
```

Comment: Hi, the "caused by" section in the details reveals that JavaFX is not on the classpath (or at least the JavaFX/SWT integration). Therefore, I would suggest to follow the adopters guide for setting up an IDE: https://github.com/eclipse/gef#set-up-an-eclipse-ide

Comment: Should I put this into an answer?